# Google beta testing: I am not able to see CURRENT/TOTAL INSTALLS for my App at Developers console

Tags: android, console-application, beta-testing

Google beta testing: I am not able to see CURRENT/TOTAL INSTALLS for my App at Developers console, though couple of users have already installed the App on their phones for more than 24 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install/uninstall stats are updated only once a day. Wait for another few hours and it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

The data is updated once a day for free apps and can take upto 48hrs for paid apps. Also this data is 6-9 hrs old at time of posting. So for example the 24 hr period ends at midnight, the data will be updated around 6am - 9am for the previous day.